# animate fade fixed back to top button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a down link that moves the page down to the next section of the website when the user click. How can i make this fade into a back to top button when the user begins to scroll. Is there also a way of fixing this into position. Guessing this would be done through Jquery but not too sure.

```
<div class="down-link"><a href="#about" id="w-downlink"><i class="ss-navigatedown"></i></a></div>


.down-link {
    width:100%;
    height:50px;    
}

#w-downlink i {
    line-height: 42px;
    font-size: 24px;
    color: #fff;
    display: block;
    width: 24px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    margin-top:10px;
}

#w-downlink {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #191919;
    background-color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.4);
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    right:0;
    margin-right:20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 1;
}

.w-downlink:hover {
    height: 60px;
    width: 60px;
    background-color: #191919;
    background-color: rgba(20, 20, 20, 0.4);
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    right:0;
    margin-right:20px;
     cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This should achieve most of what you would like; you don't need jQuery.

There's a button anchored to the top of the page and it changes when you start to scroll; this is simply CSS `position: fixed;`

The JS simply listens for a scroll event on the `window` object.

I've just edited it to also change back once the user scrolls back up the page by adding an `if(){}` statement to check for vertical scrolling.

Instead of just dumping a string into the inner HTML like I've done here, you could dump a different  element into the div.

Look into the CSS transitions if you want your element to fade.

You could either change it's class when the scroll event starts, or do it all with javascript.

Here are some resources that may help from the W3C:

[onscroll event documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onscroll.asphttp://)

[css3 Transitions](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp)

```js
var downLink = document.getElementById('down-link');
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){//Provide a window listener
  if(window.scrollY){
    downLink.innerHTML = "Back to Top";
  }else{
    downLink.innerHTML = "Down Link";
  }
  
});
```

```css
#down-link {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    border: 2px solid black /*Just to show the element bounds*/
    
  }

#userScrollElement {
    max-height:  500px;
    height: 800px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="userScrollElement">
  <div id="down-link">Down Link
  </div>
</div>
```